# How can i set interval not on the first load but second load and load after that

Tags: javascript, setinterval, invisible-recaptcha

I am using `setInterval` for my recaptcha javascript code because most of my forms are very long and the token will expire leaving the user to refill the form all over again.

And i like how the code is now EXCEPT it takes also 10 seconds for the token to load. I also have 1 input for the user to fill in and that can be submitted within 10 seconds then it will give a recaptcha error.

How can i let the code below load the first time without `setInterval` and EVERY time after the first time to be with 10 seconds interval?

Thanks for your time.

```
  setInterval(function(){
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY; ?>', {action: 'this_form'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#token').val(token);
        $('#action').val('this_form');
      });
  });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i let the code below load the first time without setInterval and EVERY time after the first time to be with 10 seconds interval?

You can use `setTimeout` for this. Give it a try:

```js
function loadCaptcha() {
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY; ?>', {action: 'this_form'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#token').val(token);
        $('#action').val('this_form');
      });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadCaptcha();
  setTimeout(function() {
    loadCaptcha();
    setInterval(loadCaptcha, 10 * 1000); // fire every 10 sec
  }, 10 * 1000); // fire only one time after 10 sec
});
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for your time and effort! :D